# Magento 2 Category Page Error

Tags: magento2, category, error, magento-2.1.4

Did a upgrade to 2.1.4 and now my Category Page is giving my an error.
I was hoping maybe someone here could point me in the right direction to fix this issue.

Below is the error log:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:73:"Attribute with attributeCode "sw_ocat_additional_content" does not exist.";i:1;s:9386:"#0 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/AttributeRepository.php(62): Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository->get('catalog_categor...', 'sw_ocat_additio...')
#1 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Category/Form/Element/Wysiwyg.php(59): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\AttributeRepository->get('sw_ocat_additio...')
#2 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Category\Form\Element\Wysiwyg->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory), Object(Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Backend\Helper\Data), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\AttributeRepository), Array, Array, Array)
#3 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
#4 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
#5 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(209): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
#6 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Field.php(82): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('sw_ocat_additio...', 'wysiwyg', Array)
#7 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(148): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare()
#8 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field))
#9 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(145): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset))
#10 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(126): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Form))
#11 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'category_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#12 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#13 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#14 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#15 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#16 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#17 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#18 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(244): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#19 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(859): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#20 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#21 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(59): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')
#22 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#23 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php(102): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#24 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit->execute()
#25 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->execute()
#26 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#29 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#30 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#33 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#36 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#39 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#40 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#43 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#45 /home/dsbooksc/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#46 {main}";s:3:"url";s:99:"/admin/catalog/category/index/key/75d44c1abda02338f4e6ef153623d3b504b5d50d1b44e9f2ce7dd2e8a116bd2f/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: Look like entry about `sw_ocat_additional_content` attribute does not exists. Search it inside `eav_attribute` table. If it is in that table then check if there is corresponding entry (same attribute_id) in `catalog_eav_attribute`.

Comment: @Zefiryn, Thanks for that.
I had a quick look in the DB and you are right I could not find it in the tables.
Im pretty new to magento. What would be my next step?

Comment: If it isn't in the database anymore then try to flush cache and reindex catalog_category_flat. If that does not help it means that some module is manually adding `sw_ocat_additional_content` to the category form. Searchthe  codebase for that string and either remove the module if you don't need it or check in Setup folder how it was defined in order to recreate it.

Comment: @Zefiryn ok will give it a go. Thank you very much.